# How do I simplify $8t^7 \left(\sqrt{t }-9\right) + t^8 \left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, expecting a detailed explanation: I already know what the answer should look like after seeing the solution for a similar problem on MyMathLab but I don't know how to reach that form.
$$8t^7 \left(\sqrt{t}-9\right) + t^8 \left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)$$

The only thing I've done is just distribute: however, that's not the solution the website will accept. After pressing similiar problem on MyMathLab it showed this as the solution's format:

[image]

Ignore the derivative part, this step is mostly just all algebra.

Comment: $$  t^7 \sqrt t =  \frac{t^8}{\sqrt t}  $$

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear to me exactly what is causing the problem. But I am assuming it's the square roots? You can rewrite them as normal exponents.

$$
\sqrt{t} = t^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
And
$$
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}} \;=\; \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \;=\; \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}} \;=\; \frac{1}{2}\cdot t^{-\frac{1}{2}}
$$